# c# web-api value of custom attribute property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Currently I'm working on a C# WebApi.

I made my own TokenAuthorizationAttribute, which checks if the string in the "Authorization"-Header matches the string in a Database. 
This works just fine, I can decorate controllers and methods with the attribute and it works.

However now I'm trying to write a method that uses the passed token. Of course i could read out the header again, but i don't want to do that because it needs time (and the method has to work fast). I thought of maybe saving the token to a property of the TokenAuthorizationAttribute, but how can i get the value of it in my method?

Here's the code of my Attribute:

```
    public class TokenAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext) {

        public string Token {get; set;}

        IEnumerable<string> values;

        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out values)) {
            string token = values.FirstOrDefault();
            string auth = String.Empty;

            SqlConnection conn = SqlService.OpenConnection();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT-Token-Statement", conn);
            auth = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            conn.Close();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth)) {
                Token = auth;
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
            else {
                actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                    ReasonPhrase = "Wrong Token"
                };
            }
        }
        else{
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized){
                ReasonPhrase = "Missing Token"
```

and my method looks something like that:

```
[TokenAuthorization]
public static void MyMethod(string value) {
     string token = "How do i get the Token?";
}
```

Comment: I did a little project that uses JsonWebTokens for authorization on WebApi2 https://github.com/AtomStar/WebApiSecure. Maybe it is of use to you...

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had a few good ideas while reading your code.